# Connect to server with SFTP instead of FTP/FTPS within WordPress Backup

Tags: server, ftp

I have recently setup a Linode Apache2 Debian server and I am hosting my WordPress site on it. It seems I can only connect to the server with SFTP.

When I attempt to add/update a plugin I am presented with this screen:

[image]

There doesn't appear to be an option to use SFTP instead of FTP or FTPS. I cannot find any plugins or anything to do this.

Because of this, I cannot add/update plugins.

What are my options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a permissions issue:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
```

Comment: ...and leave your front door unlocked. And write the pin number for your credit card on post-it note and stick it on the back of the card.

Answer (score 1):

I use [SSH SFTP Updater Support](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ssh-sftp-updater-support/) and it works fine. From the project description:

> "SSH SFTP Updater Support" is the easiest way to keep your WordPress
>   installation up-to-date with SFTP.

Comment: the plugin wasn't updated for 2 years, probably unmaintained

Comment: Actually it's the only sftp plugin and I use it since years without problems. So right now, I don't see a different solution.

Comment: for me the question is stupid. the different solution is either do it the slow way, use wp-cli or just setup an ftp server with only local access. installing some thing that is not maintained is just not a good security practice especially in security oriented plugin

Comment: I have to agree with @MarkKaplun, out of the presented options, I would go with the wp-cli, but unfortunately my requirements mean that the plugins *need* to be managed via the CMS

Comment: The mentioned plugin is supported again, so I maintain my recommendation.